# Missing chunk on the edge of mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm just starting out trying to learn blender so this may sound like a stupid question but while I was making this model a chunk of the mesh randomly cut out without me realizing. I'm trying to get back the original mesh with the grid line in between but I can't seem to find a solution. I've found one solution to try to get the face back by selecting all the edge in edit mode and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.

It worked to fill the missing piece but I can't get back the original grid line that cut that section of the face in half. To fix this I tried to subdivide the bottom edge to get a vertex in the middle and then I clicked on the vertex and the one across from it and right clicked and selected new face/face from vertices but that made it look weird as below. Don't know where to go from here.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Select the bottom edge of the "gap" (the big square), right click and select "subdivide". Select the new vertex that is created, and while holding shift, select the one directly above it as well. Press J (join) to connect them. If it still looks weird, select the whole mesh (A) and press M (merge), and select "by distance" then press Ctrl+Shift+N (recalculate normals outside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but notice that there is a curvature so you can't just connect them together. I would do it as illustrated in the GIF animation.

In *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>1</kbd> to go into *Vertex Select* mode and select to check any of the bottom vertices' location in the *Item* tab. In this example their Z-location is $-1$. Select the vertex as shown and press <kbd>E</kbd> for Extrude and then immediately hit <kbd>Z</kbd> to extrude on the Z-axis. Then position anywhere and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. Then manually set the Z-position to the same value as its neighbors (which is $-1$ in my case). Select 4 vertices at a time and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill a face in each quad space.

[image]

To make sure you have no duplicate overlapping vertices, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices and press <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance*.

And also while editing a mesh, I would recommend disabling the subdivision modifier and turning it back on when you're done with the edits using this button highlighted in yellow:

[image]